# Foolproof RequiredIfTrue not working for MVC5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-5, foolproof-validation

I am trying conditional required field. If user selects `ContactByPhone` checkbox I am showing `ContactPhoneNumber` field and it should be required filed. If user doesn't select `ContactByPhone` then `ContactPhoneNumber` is invisible and not required.

Validation is not showing on client side. and after I submit the form `ModelState.IsValid` is false for this property.

How to handle this? I think I referenced all scripts on the page. Do we have any alternative solution for this situation?

### Model

```
public class Contact
{
  [Display(Name = "by Phone")]
  public bool ContactByPhone { get; set; }

  [RequiredIfTrue("ContactByPhone", ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required")]
  public string ContactPhoneNumber { get; set; }

}
```

### Index.cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/Index.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.notifyBar.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-5 text-left">
           @Html.Label("How do you want to be contacted?", new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ContactByPhone, new { @style = "margin-top: 8px"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="divContactPhone" hidden>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactPhoneNumber, new { @class = "control-label-nobold" })<span class="red">*</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactPhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactPhoneNumber, "", new { @style = "color:Red" })
          </div>
    </div>
```

### Controller

[image]

### Generated HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <input class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-requiredif="Phone number is required" data-val-requiredif-dependentproperty="ContactByPhone" data-val-requiredif-dependentvalue="True" data-val-requiredif-operator="EqualTo" id="ContactPhoneNumber" name="ContactPhoneNumber" type="text" value="" maxlength="15" autocomplete="off"> 
     <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ContactPhoneNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true" style="color:Red"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're missing `MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js` and `MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js` JS files. See example below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-5 text-left">
                @Html.Label("How do you want to be contacted?", new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ContactByPhone, new { @id = "myCheckBox", @style = "margin-top: 8px" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactByPhone)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="divContactPhone">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactPhoneNumber, new { @class = "control-label-nobold" })<span class="red">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactPhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactPhoneNumber, "", new { @style = "color:Red" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-5 text-left">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#divContactPhone").hide();
        $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
            $("#divContactPhone").toggle('show');
        });
    </script>
}
```

Note: I used jquery to control the hidden div element.

Comment: Can you please share the project? I am getting `uncaught referenceerror sys is not defined` in jquery 1.10.2 after adding these libraries.

Comment: You mean to upload the project to somewhere?

Comment: You need to use NuGet to download "MVC Foolproof Validation" and "Mvc Extensions.Foolproof". You might be missing one of them.

Comment: thanks for that. this time I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ValidatorRegistry' of undefined` in jquery. Please my references on the page `http://i.stack.imgur.com/vBoJ6.png`. I was loading this checkbox on fancybox on link click. So fancybox not all loading if I add this.

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly the problem exists. But I can give you some suggestions. 1) make sure you enabled ClientValidationEnabled in Web.config file. 2) If you don't need MicrosoftAjax.js file, don't use it. 3) sometimes the order of JS files matter, make sure the order is correct. 4) use BundleConfig class to manage your JS files for different type of JS files. this will reduce your page loading time. 5) See this link, it may help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/11/adding-client-side-script-to-an-mvc-conditional-validator.aspx

Comment: It's worth noting that the [Codeplex docs](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) seem to indicate that you only load the `mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js` file, so this suggestion is likely incorrect.

Comment: I'm getting this error as well. As @TiesonT. suggested, the codeplex only mentions the need to reference mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js. Adding the other files doesn't help.